# @yield não exibe o conteúdo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou aprendendo Laravel 5.1, me deparei com um erro ao utilizar o `@yield`. Não consigo passar o conteúdo de outro arquivo para o arquivo onde quero incluir.

A seguir tenho o conteúdo que quero inserir no arquivo `default-home.blade.php` dentro da pasta layouts:

```
@extends('layouts.default-home')
@section('content')      

<section id="feature_two">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Feature Two Description -->
        <div id="feature_2_description" class="col-md-5 feature_description triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="fadeInLeft">

            <h2>Super easy to customize and well detailed for beginners</h2>

            <p>Vestibulum at est vel felis adipiscing tincidunt. Proin quis diam ac lectus pretium mollis interdum sed erat. Phasellus eget
                neque eu ipsum laoreet suscipit tincidunt suscipit purus rutrum 
            </p>

            <p>Etiam euismod, ligula nec volutpat tempor, risus lerisque tincidunt purus libero. Fusce tincidunt ligula, nec sagittis turpis</p>

        </div><!-- End Feature Two Description -->

        <!-- Feature Two Image -->
        <div id="feature_2_image" class="col-md-7 feature_image text-right triggerAnimation animated" data-animate="fadeInRight">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/thumbs/feature_two_img.png" alt="feature_two_img">
        </div>

    </div><!-- End row -->  
</div><!-- End container -->
</section>

@stop
```

Este é  arquivo com o `@yield` inserido, os `@includes` estão funcionando:

```
<body class="notransition"  ng-app>

    @include('layouts.head-home')
    @yield('content') 
    @include('layouts.footer-home')

    <div id="status"></div>

</body>
```

No caso, o site que estou desenvolvendo utiliza os links no menu para pular para outra parte do site mais abaixo, além desse conteúdo não exibir o console apresenta este erro toda vez que rolo a página ou clico no link para a rolagem:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Arquivo routes.php :

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


Route::get('','Site\HomeController@home');
Route::get('/','Site\HomeController@home');


?>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function home(){
        return view('site/home'); //chamando a view home.blade.php
    }
}
```

Comment: O segundo arquivo que seria o `layouts/default-home.blade.php`?

Comment: Sim, é o conteúdo do arquivo default-home.blade.php

Comment: e como é o nome do arquivo que quer incluir? está chamando o arquivo correto na sua route ?

Comment: Eu preciso chamar no route essa parte do arquivo?No caso tudo fica numa unica página e acontece os saltos para outra parte. O meu arquivo de route está assim: Route::get('','Site\HomeController@home');
Route::get('/','Site\HomeController@home');

Comment: Acho melhor incluir seu arquivo routes.php na pergunta, clique em [edit] e insira o mesmo por gentileza.

Comment: Ah! o erro está no controller. Troque a barra por um ponto. `return view('site.home');`. O Laravel segue essa convenção para as views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir dos comentários notei alguns problemas que precisam ser corrigidos.

No arquivo de rotas, você define duas vezes uma rota para `Site\HomeController@home`. A rota `''` acaba sendo desnecessária, então você pode eliminar ela:

```
<?php

Route::get('/','Site\HomeController@home');
```

Outro ponto, sua rota está apontando para a classe `HomeController` dentro do diretório `app/Http/Controllers/Site`. Como a aplicação do Laravel segue o [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), o namespace desse controller precisa conter o final `Site`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;
```

Se não tem um bom motivo para mover o controller para uma sub pasta, mantenha do jeito que está dentro da pasta `app/Http/Controllers`.

---

Corrigido esses problemas, vamos a exibição da view.

Para retornar a view com o conteúdo na sua página inicial, basta retornar o caminho da view dessa forma no método `home` do `HomeController`:

```
public function home(){
    return view('main');  
    // caso a view esteja em alguma pasta, utilize o . como separador
    // como você fez com o layouts.default-home
    // return view('pasta.main');  
}
```

Por fim, você pode retornar a página diretamente do arquivos de rotas por uma função anonima, assim elimina a necessidade do controller em páginas simples:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pasta.main');
});
```

Comment: mesmo fazendo desta forma: return view('site.home'); ele nao exibe o conteúdo

Comment: o arquivo `home` está em que pasta?

Comment: O conteúdo que desejo exibir está num arquivo dentro de resources/views/layouts/. Com o nome produtos.blade.php

Comment: `view('site.home')` vai procurar pelo arquivo `resources/views/site/home.blade.php`. Se quer exibir o arquivo `resources/views/layouts/produtos.blade.php` tem que retornar na view `view('layouts.produtos)`

Comment: Conteúdo que deve ser inserido no arquivo default-home.blade.php através do @yield

Comment: Estou tentando chamar a home com o conteúdo de produtos pelo @yield, isso é possível? Pois devem estar na mesma página.

Comment: Ok, fiz a modificação para view('layouts.produtos) como você recomendou e deu certo. Muito obrigada.

Comment: O `layouts.default-home` é o arquivo modelo do seu template. Você não chama ele diretamente pela view. É preciso chamar um segundo arquivo que herde o conteúdo de `layouts.default-home`, que é o que você definiu em `@extends(layouts.default-home)`, Entendeu ?

Comment: Sim entendi, mas e se eu tiver mais views que herdem layouts.default-home, como eu devo chamar na Controller?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26172/discussion-between-gmsantos-and-let).